# Ordering NULL results differently in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I have a query that currently brings up data like this:

```
ID | Name | Arrival  | Departure
-----------------------------------
1  | John | NULL     |  2:30:00
2  | John | NULL     | 11:00:00
3  | John | NULL     | 14:00:00
4  | John | 10:30:00 | 11:00:00
5  | John | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00
```

This is when I do: `order by Name, Arrival, Departure`.

However, what I would like instead is the following:

1. If the Arrival entry is `NULL`, then rows should be ordered by the
   Departure column.
2. If the Arrival entry is `NULL` AND
   there are multiple rows with the same Departure data, then it
   should be ordered **after** the other rows that have an Arrival
   entry.

Result:

```
ID | Name | Arrival  | Departure
-----------------------------------
1  | John | NULL     |  2:30:00
4  | John | 10:30:00 | 11:00:00
2  | John | NULL     | 11:00:00
5  | John | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00
3  | John | NULL     | 14:00:00
```

Edit: For those who thought this is a duplicate question - originally the questions are not the same due to the second condition. However, because of the way my data is structured (Arrival times are always before Departure times), the same answer is applicable.

Edit 2: Departure can be NULL as well. When Departure is null, the Arrival entry is non-null. If this is the case, it should be ordered by Arrival. If two rows both have the same Arrival entry, then NULLs should be BEFORE non-nulls. Note this is opposite to NULL Arrival entries (condition 2 above), where NULLs are after non-nulls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional ORDER BY depending on column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464434/conditional-order-by-depending-on-column-values)

Comment: The second rule is somewhat unclear to me. Do you mean that if arrival in row 4 would be 11:00:00, it should always go before a row that has null arrival and a 11:00:00 departure?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I mean for rows with Departure values that are the same, then entries with null Arrival values should be below the rows with non-null Arrival values. The reason I mentioned it is because normally NULLs are ordered before non-null values. In the intended results above, row 4 is above row 2, because it has a non-null Arrival value.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson To answer your question, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Arrival TIME,Departure TIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'John',NULL,'2:30:00')
,(2,'John',NULL,'11:00:00')
,(3,'John',NULL,'14:00:00')
,(4,'John','10:30:00','11:00:00')
,(5,'John','12:00:00','13:00:00');

SELECT * FROM @tbl
ORDER BY Name,CASE WHEN Arrival IS NULL THEN Departure ELSE Arrival END
```

The result

```
1   John    NULL                02:30:00.0000000
4   John    10:30:00.0000000    11:00:00.0000000
2   John    NULL                11:00:00.0000000
5   John    12:00:00.0000000    13:00:00.0000000
3   John    NULL                14:00:00.0000000
```

You might think about `ISNULL()`, but you should read about "sargable", especially if you deal with many rows and indexes...

Comment: Uncredited duplicate of this answer?   http://stackoverflow.com/a/7464492/1507566

Comment: There aren't a ton of different ways to accomplish what the OP wanted so it shouldn't be a surprise that another person might have come to the same conclusion.

Comment: I did not vote you down but there is no rule a down vote requires a comment

Comment: @Paparazzi, no, but I think that this is a matter of politness... Anyway, I use down votes very rarely and ever explain why...

Comment: @Shnugo If it is a matter of politeness then it should not be ! with an order.  That wording is not a polite request (IMHO).

Comment: @Paparazzi, you might read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). But to be honest: This is not important enough to quarrel about :-) Happy coding!

Comment: @Shnugo I did read it.  Did you?  Would you not consider "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" much more polite than your ! order.

Comment: This wouldn't quite work if the arrival time in row 4 was `11:00:00` instead of `10:30:00`, because then the ordering of row 2 and row 4 is ambiguous. Luckily for me, there isn't a case when the Arrival time is the same as (or behind) the Departure time. So I guess this answer's good!

Comment: @Shnugo, Thank you for providing the script with the test data.

Answer (score 1):

How about simple `ORDER` without conditional expressions and functions.

If you want to order by `Departure` first, well, order by it.
If you want to order by `Arrival` next, but want `NULL` last, use `DESC`.

This will work correctly even if `Arrival` is the same as `Departure`, for example, if `Arrival` was `11:00:00` in row 4 instead of `10:30:00`.

I'd like to thank @Shnugo for providing the script with the test data.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Arrival TIME,Departure TIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'John',NULL,'2:30:00')
,(2,'John',NULL,'11:00:00')
,(3,'John',NULL,'14:00:00')
,(4,'John','10:30:00','11:00:00')
,(5,'John','12:00:00','13:00:00');

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY
    Name
    ,Departure
    ,Arrival DESC;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------+------------------+------------------+
| ID | Name |     Arrival      |    Departure     |
+----+------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | John | NULL             | 02:30:00.0000000 |
|  4 | John | 10:30:00.0000000 | 11:00:00.0000000 |
|  2 | John | NULL             | 11:00:00.0000000 |
|  5 | John | 12:00:00.0000000 | 13:00:00.0000000 |
|  3 | John | NULL             | 14:00:00.0000000 |
+----+------+------------------+------------------+
```

Though... It is not clear if it is possible to have more than one row with non-null `Arrival` and exactly the same `Departure`... What ordering you'd like in this case?

Comment: There should not be more than one row with non-null `Arrival` and the same `Departure`. But, one thing which I did not mention in OP is that `Departure` can be null too. If they are null then the respective `Arrival` is non-null. In those cases it should be ordered by `Arrival`.

Comment: @painiyff, well, in this case you'd have to use some expression with `CASE` or `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do case statements in an order by clause I believe.

ISNULL would be my preferred way to go though because it's specifically built to work with nulls and it's smaller.

```
ORDER BY Name, ISNULL(Arival, Departure)
```

Comment: No, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024090/sargable-queries-using-isnull-in-tsql), Btw: I'm not the down voter...

Comment: True.  Yours is the more complete answer.

Comment: So, it is not sargable.  It works.  +1  I doubt the have a lot of rows in that table.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes readability is a goal all of its own when it comes to coding.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid using conditionals in `WHERE` clause you can persist your ordering criteria by using a computed column. Also, using [TIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.110).aspx) type for the Arrival and Departure is more efficient (space, comparisons etc.):

```
create table Data 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Arrival TIME NULL,
    Departure TIME NULL,
    ActualTime AS ISNULL(Arrival, Departure) PERSISTED
)
GO

INSERT INTO Data (ID, Name, Arrival, Departure)
VALUES
 (1,'John',NULL,'2:30:00')
,(2,'John',NULL,'11:00:00')
,(3,'John',NULL,'14:00:00')
,(4,'John','10:30:00','11:00:00')
,(5,'John','12:00:00','13:00:00');
GO

select * from Data
order by ActualTime
```

Based on other queries, you can also have an index using `ActualTime` as a key.

Answer (score 0):

To get null to come last I think you can just add

```
ORDER BY Name 
       , ISNULL(Arival, dateadd(ss, 1, Departure)) 
       , Departure
```

but if you have arrival that go into the next departure with nulls then you are going to get some maybe not desired results
you would need to state exactly how you want to deal with that

what if you had

```
6  | John | 12:30:00 | 11:00:00
```

do you really want that after

```
5  | John | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00
```

it would be a lot easier to just sort on departure first

```
declare @bigdate datetime = cast('2099-01-01' as datetime);
ORDER BY Name  
       , Departure 
       , ISNULL(Arival, @bigdate);
```